# Android Studio: "Update & Restart" doesn't work

Tags: android-studio

Every morning after start of Android Studio I became a dialog with information about new version of Android Studio (Beta). If I click on "Update & Restart" the patch will be downloaded (I see the progress bar and the growing file size). After that the Android Studio will be restarted but... the update is not installed! I can repeat it if I click on "Help/Check for update".

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

P.S. Sure it is possible to download the full version and install it manually, but it would be so convenient to use automatically updates.

Comment: Are you on Windows, with it installed for all users?

Comment: No, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 1.2 Preview 1 & 2? Acording to the link below "Update & Restart" Doesn't Restart and the solution is manually exit the IDE, and start it again. http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Comment: Thank you, Jorge, for your proposal. I've found the solution by accident. See my answer below.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've solved the problem. It is important how Android Studio was started. If I start it with a workspace parameter:

```
/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /<path_to_workspace>
```

then the update doesn't work.

So the solution is to start the Android Studio without any parameters.

Comment: then how do u start the android studio normally

Comment: @AjayVenugopal, normally I start it with one of my desktop shortcuts which points to a particular workspace.

Comment: Still the issue exists and Studio team hasn't fixed it yet. Great solution!!

Comment: Got the same issue when I run studio for update from root without params. It seems that update mechanism does not work at all. AS 2.0 beta 6, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I used /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Then I chose no workspace and then updated Android Studio successfully.
Then I chose to import workspace and it worked...
Thanks

Comment: normally I run android studio with the following command with no workspace  argument

sudo ./home/username/android-studio/bin/studio.sh 


but the problem remains

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Same, I'm not providing any arguments and running Studio by `sudo ./studio.sh` but problem remains on Ubuntu.

Comment: Was having this also: Android Studio would download the patch and close, but would fail to restart. Launching manually would reveal old version still present. The fix for me was to avoid using the launcher, and instead, run studio.sh from the command line.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day.

Comment: This still worked for me for 2.3.3 to 3.0. I just launched the 64 bit version in the Android Studio bin directory and it updated.

Answer (score 7):

I successfully updated my AS from 2.1.1 to 2.2.2, by the following way:

1. File > Close Project. Close AS.
2. restart AS, it will not open any project and show you a project list, but please don't open any project.
3. wait for AS to popup a dialog to remind you there is a new version.
4. click "update & restart".
5. after restart, it may remind you import previous configuration files.
6. import configuration, open a project, you will see the new version number.

hope this will help.

Comment: can you provide more explanation how will this solve the problem?

Comment: It didn't do a thing, and why it will anyway? what the difference between hit the "update and restart" from a project or from the main window?

Comment: Still relevant, closing the project was necessary for the upgrade from 3.5 to 3.6.1 to work.

Comment: This worked for me upgrading from Arctic Fox to Bumblebee on two different computers.  Great tip!

Answer (score 2):

I actually created [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233494) and it seems they fixed it in the latest release and you have to download it manually from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#linux-bundle) and update mechanism should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it happened to me just now.
In case you installed the Android Studio via [JetBrain's Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) then the button is disabled if you start the AS manually. You need to close the AS and open the Toolbox and then update from there.

[image]