# "Update and Restart" button in android studio 2.1.3 is not working when i try to update it to version 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I received the message for updating android studio to version 2.2 (I'm currently using version 2.1.3 on Windows 7) but when I click on the button "Update & Restart" it does download the patch but when it restarts, it doesn't apply it. 
I saw an answer to a similar question in this link [Android Studio: "Update & Restart" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379665/android-studio-update-restart-doesnt-work/30673777#30673777)
but the answer only explains how to handle the issue on Linux while i'm using windows and I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.
thank you in advance for your aswers.

Comment: If there's an additional option for closing Android Studio and updating through the alternative, do all updates you need in there, restart AS. Once AS is open, you may need to install a few further updates for the message to go away, assuming the update can be installed with AS opened.

Comment: there's not this option, for the update you need to have AS running

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. I thought this was referring to the problem where AS will claim you have updates for android, but won't always actually apply the updates. You may wish to just manually download the installer from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I just invalidated caches, restarted AS and then updated and it worked for me.
**File->Invalidate Caches/Restart**