# Android Studio “Update and Restart” button is disable

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio is version：4.2 Beta 5 , and I want to update it to stable version- 4.2.2.
When I check the version ,an updating window pop out, but the "Update and Restart" button is disable to click. What can i do to complete the updating work?

Thanks everyone’s answer for me. Someone says I need to uninstall the beta version , but the window show the patch size for updating beta version to stable version, There must be some way to do so without uninstall step .

[image]

Comment: To the close voters voting to close this as "General computing": Android Studio is a _programming_ tool.  This close reason clearly does not apply.  I will vote to reopen if this is closed for that reason.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673777/208273)?

Comment: @Ryan M Thanks, but my problem is different with that case you post . In my case ,I even can't click the update button.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Android Studio manually, reboot your system and problem solved.

Comment: What does "clear cache of your system" mean?  There's no system-wide cache that you can just clear on a macOS system.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt read the picture though. I thought it was windows so you can clear temp files and folders on windows. Let me edit

Comment: Is this answer based on having seen similar issues before or is it just a guess? If not, is clearing the cache necessary on Windows but not on macOS?

Comment: @RyanM I haven't used a mac before. I am on Windows 11 right now

Comment: Clearing cache on Windows isn't necessary, but clearing them can make the system fast and all the glitches can also be solved

Comment: I haven't seen a question like this, i am encountering it first time

Comment: My question is more: why do you suggest that restarting the IDE, then the computer will fix this particular issue?

Comment: Restarting the IDE invalidates all caches and hence the problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235373/discussion-between-just-kidding-and-ryan-m).

Comment: @RyanM Can you please inspect my profile and answer my latest question. Thanks. And we will continue dicussion in chat. I am eating

Comment: Invalidating all caches  not works, sad.

Comment: Try restarting not invalidating caches.

Comment: If it doesn't work, export all your projects to a safe folder and then unistall and install Android Studio from the original website. https://developer.android.com/studio

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall and install the latest version of android studio,
Because beta to stable required to uninstall studio.

Comment: Can i uninstall the beta version without the loss of development environment?

Comment: Take android studio folder backup from c drive and then after delete.